# Added ScrollView In Constaint Layout With GridLayout Its Not Working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, grid-layout

I am trying to make a dashboard that looks like this on [this link](https://github.com/abdulazizahwan/MyCollegeApp), but with one column

I want to make the dashboard to be scrollable.

I want to add a ScrollView on the below code.I have tried every means but it keeps distorting the GridLayout.

I have tried adding the ScrollView above GriLayout. It completely distorts the GridLayout.

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.Dashboard">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bg_top_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_topheader"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:rowCount="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bg_top_header"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="HouseHold Register"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="MOH 513"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="Service Delivery Logbook"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="MOH 514"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="Diarrhoea Baseline"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="Survey"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!----Other Views----->


    </GridLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Lemmy, please add a screenshot of UI.

Comment: Hello Happy i have edited the question

Comment: I will suggest you use a recycler view with a grid layout manager.  so your boilerplate code from XML will remove and it comes under in best practice.

Comment: use this link for more clarity, https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example

Comment: I updated your code and it's working fine. check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add ScrollView as a root of the Layout and add constraint layout as its child.

I had edited your code. please try there are some changes I did. it is working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".activity.Dashboard"
    >

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop"
        />

<View
        android:id="@+id/bg_top_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_topheader"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />


<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
        >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >


        <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnCount="1"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:rowCount="5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bg_top_header"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                >


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                    >

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="HouseHold Register"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="MOH 513"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="30sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                    >

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Service Delivery Logbook"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="MOH 514"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="30sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                    >

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Diarrhoea Baseline"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Survey"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="30sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                    >

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Diarrhoea Baseline"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Survey"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="30sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                    >

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Diarrhoea Baseline"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Survey"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="30sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/whiteColor"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
                    >

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Diarrhoea Baseline"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                                android:text="Survey"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                                android:textSize="30sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </GridLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You should not use GridView inside a ScrollView, In the documentation
>   also its mention the same.

**You can use LinearLayout with vertical orientation inside a ScrollView and put all your items inside that layout.**

As per your need i am updating your code, you can replace your code with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.Dashboard">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bg_top_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_topheader"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bg_top_header"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="HouseHold Register"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="MOH 513"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="Service Delivery Logbook"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="MOH 514"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@mipmap/rgil_glasses"
                    android:gravity="start" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="Diarrhoea Baseline"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                        android:text="Survey"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!----Other Views----->

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```